# CSS is Lost when adding Search DIV to Joomla 3.0 Component View

Tags: php, search, joomla, styles, components

I have found that when this code snippet is added to the view of a custom component that I am creating then I am losing the default styling from the admin panel.

```
        <div class="btn-group pull-right hidden-phone">
            <label for="limit" class="element-invisible"><?php echo JText::_('JFIELD_PLG_SEARCH_SEARCHLIMIT_DESC');?></label>
            <?php echo $this->pagination->getLimitBox(); ?>
        </div>
```

Any ideas as to why that could be happening?

---

I have also found that this code is dropping styling as well on the same view:

`<?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?>`

This makes me think that it has something to do with the `$this->pagination` where is this typically defined for a view?

---

Alright another update...

I have now cleared out those styling issues and see that the underlying issue has to do with the `$this` variable.  I have another PHP call where the view should pull data from the database like this:

```
<?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) :
            $ordering   = ($listOrder == 'a.ordering');
            $canCreate  = $user->authorise('core.create',       'com_bbmaps');
            $canEdit    = $user->authorise('core.edit',         'com_bbmaps');
            $canCheckin = $user->authorise('core.manage',       'com_bbmaps');
            $canChange  = $user->authorise('core.edit.state',   'com_bbmaps');
            ?>
```

But again, I see errors-->

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Ultimately my question is where do I define the database that `$this` relates to?

---

The only place that I am seeing `$this` defined is in the controller.php file:

```
public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false)
{
    require_once JPATH_COMPONENT.'/helpers/componenthelper.php';

    $view       = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('view', 'userdatas');
    JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('view', $view);

    parent::display($cachable, $urlparams);

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see it is referencing the `userdatas` view.  I have created a new view that is called `photos` from the `userdatas` view.  How can I go about telling the `photos` view to pull `$this` from the new database?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you closed all the opened tags.
I've had the same problem when I forgot to close some previously opened  or other tag.
Sometimes the closing  is mistakenly replaced with a  by some editors' autocomplete functionality.

-- EDIT --

Please also check your server's error log if you hadn't enabled the php.ini display_errors directive. There could be an error in your component which you don't see on the page. When there is a "fatal" PHP error the execution is stopped, so is stopped the further rendering.

-- SECOND EDIT --

You could try to replace the following:

```
<?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) :
```

with:

```
<?php if (!empty($this->items) :
          foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) :
```

and then close the "if" after the "endforeach":

```
    endforeach;
endif;
```

This should fix the "invalid argument" error.

P.S.: In this scenario $this will most probably correspond to the template object which has all the properties that are assigned for it to use.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I have copied this view from a pre-existing admin view that is working fine, so it should not have a syntax error with the tags.  I have updated the question with more details that may give a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: thank you for the additional information.  I have checked the apache error logs and nothing is there.  Rather than cutting out each item that is off I would rather take care of the root issue with the `$this` variable.  I found more related code in `controller.php` and just updated the question with that info.